# ELB Private IPs keep changing, breaking target security rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have an ELB pointing to a target.  On the target I have a rule to only allow traffic from the two IP addresses of this ELB.  They are 172.something.something.something

It seems that these two IP addresses change!  When this happens the app breaks, and so we then find the new IPs and update the security rule with the new values.  This is a terrible solution!

What is the right way to tell an EC2 instance that it can only get calls on a certain port from the Elastic Load Balancer that points to the instance?

Afaik you can only make Security Rules which have an IP address and a port number/range.

Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Use security groups for firewall rule matching, from ELB to EC2 and vice-versa, not IP addresses. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-groups.html). The security group for the EC2 instances allow inbound HTTPS from the ELB's security group, for example.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Load Balancer IP addresses are not permanent, they will change all the time. This is covered in the AWS documentation. You have to refer to the load balancer's security group ID in your EC2 instance's security group rules, instead of the load balancer's IP address.

> Afaik you can only make Security Rules which have an IP address and a port number/range.

That's not true at all. You can reference other security groups in security group rules.

Comment: What is "the load balancer's security group"?  It it just any old group you then assign to the ELB?  This is where I get stuck.  And I do understand that I can use a security group id in another security group rule.  But sounds like we need one blank group just for the ELB, and then on our EC2 instance make a rule allowing that group on the desired port.

Comment: The load balancer has to have a security group assigned to it. Just like the EC2 instance has to have a security group assigned to it. The terminology "the load balancer's security group" means "the security group that you assigned to the load balancer". The load balancer can't have a "blank" group, because then no traffic would be able to reach the load balancer. The load balancer has to have a security group that allows inbound traffic. If you don't already have a security group assigned to your load balancer then the load balancer will not be accessible at all.

Comment: You should have one security group dedicated to your load balancer and nothing else. And you should have another security group dedicated to the EC2 instances behind the load balancer, and nothing else.